# spring boot: getting this error - Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, url

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/study?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.16'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

so, basically, I am trying to starting the setup for spring boot with Intellij using gradle.

and my db is mysql.

Thing is I searched every pieces of information regarding the error I am getting. But they are not helpful. I put all information needed for spring datasource in application.properties. and the location of it is correct which is under src/main/resources.

I don't know why it keeps getting this error below.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63471:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\el-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\ojdbc6.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\sboot\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.8.RELEASE\69a67eefdc71a6dbddc752fca94b39a49e06c435\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.8.RELEASE\c728aa5023666554b74b57ee5edf0e47ba0af82b\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.projectlombok\lombok\1.18.8\448003bc1b234aac04b58e27d7755c12c3ec4236\lombok-1.18.8.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.8.RELEASE\36c0b75eaf07a68ac6e8a75c97a2bffa766ac147\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.8.RELEASE\4978a5e339411af2934bdbb44640687748f4588b\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.8.RELEASE\910f1e7ee86175e16c1075cd714a1053453ece7d\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.37\2c378637f6faff77541244e8257b446f04324bd8\mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.8.RELEASE\18f402a493e49571624ff03b584032d499c66177\spring-boot-starter-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\6c66db1c636ee90beb4c65fe34abd8ba9396bca6\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.10.RELEASE\12639406aa28c3a5195a1a4c9077fe562f54bc31\spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.1.9.RELEASE\220169d217f7114706141fc0afba425a5b368dce\spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.9.RELEASE\3fd70356ba8d7c00c4081c1a207766352624414e\spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\e006adf5cf3cca2181d16bd640ecb80148ec0fce\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.xml.bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\8531ad5ac454cc2deb9d4d32c40c4d7451939b5d\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.11.Final\8ca0850acb59ffda12729cb6d9a0c6bb3ba61b68\hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.9.RELEASE\a8aec853c345ed54a99627cee9f755ce7dbb734\spring-aspects-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.8.RELEASE\c36ad84fd6b814fd0ffbc6e0a594ca4a44b70318\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\af73055fc4a103ab347c56e7da5a143d68a0170\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.9.RELEASE\b9d4a2140488f0e6f9aa231e7938ae18da77b637\spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.1.9.RELEASE\9fe4390420fdd0b63dc4ed90d9027dafa9f74f80\spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.8.RELEASE\f243a54d052621fdc0ab5b2352d42cab1c05e2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.1.8.RELEASE\d37969b66e4a6d274f4100c22242ae15a260d529\spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.8.RELEASE\ccd951d24bb3031e2ffab287fc66cf8efcb08436\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.1.9.RELEASE\a9125e2c8eeb193030f3972c6293616943c55ef2\spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.1.9.RELEASE\c37f8fe15a5ae4ea1f351bd46167fd492a84eefa\spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.1.9.RELEASE\bc2312ffad02251b9d472e4a7c0e472a58f50fbf\spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.1.10.RELEASE\c73a76070181b59b19df6893e1ca729263a69b47\spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.1.9.RELEASE\5a03b3983108d73978aec2fa3e681aedad6782c\spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.1.9.RELEASE\db3a2468c1b7d697ec3b3ec6e5652dc282994fe3\spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.1.9.RELEASE\dc3815439579b4fa0c19970e6b8e5d774af8d988\spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\6d37bf7b046c0ce2669f26b99365a2cfa45c4c18\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\c6f06c420ad62d3824b38a06dfdce9fb55ba81ef\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\2cd9b264f76e3d087ee21bfc99305928e1bdb443\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\ec62d74fe50689c28c0ff5b35d3aebcaa8b5be68\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\9205229878f3d62fbd3a32a0fb6be2d6ad8589a9\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\965a18fdf939ee75e41f7918532d37b3a8350535\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.3.Final\d3cfa8d3075fd52884fc82ded5c52b1407f18e6e\jboss-logging-3.3.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\25665ac8c0b62f50e6488173233239120fc52c96\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.23.2-GA\c5afe660a95e87ceb518e4f5cf02f5c56b547683\javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.16\e7d63009be7b87ff1f15b72e5b8c59c897a8d8bd\byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\7060f67764565b9ee9d467e3ed0cb8a9c601b23a\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\291658ac2ce2476256c7115943652c0accb5c857\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\3dce5dbb3571aa820c677fadd8349bfa8f00c199\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.9\4b04126963103216c9c43b0f34bbc36315654204\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.9\a33df137557793b0404a486888dbe049f7abeeeb\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.9\a92facb55a2538e7b2fe14294570a18b823ad431\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.9.3\68ddd453458765757fd3ffca9437f9a42d91003e\jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.24\2114edf511f94cb22159ec1bbcba37bcbdf9a9bd\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.24\ddf2ecf6976876e2569d507f033c613f6fa18f14\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.24\247854025c365cce5513cfd7bdcffc2fc2d74dd1\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.24.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.9.RELEASE\7c372790c999777d20f364960cf557dd74f890cf\spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.9\bfff5af9fb8347d26bbb7959cb9b4fe9a2b0ca5e\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\유광민\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\f5e9a2ffca496057d6891a3de65128efc636e26e\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar" com.example.study.StudyApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-13 20:27:40.398  INFO 29888 --- [           main] com.example.study.StudyApplication       : Starting StudyApplication on KwangStark with PID 29888 (C:\sboot\build\classes\java\main started by 유광민 in C:\sboot)
2019-09-13 20:27:40.435  INFO 29888 --- [           main] com.example.study.StudyApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-13 20:27:43.676  INFO 29888 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-13 20:27:43.775  INFO 29888 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 66ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-09-13 20:27:44.840  INFO 29888 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64ec8457] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-13 20:27:46.238  INFO 29888 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-13 20:27:46.396  INFO 29888 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-13 20:27:46.397  INFO 29888 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-13 20:27:47.216  INFO 29888 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-13 20:27:47.216  INFO 29888 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6525 ms
2019-09-13 20:27:47.421  WARN 29888 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2019-09-13 20:27:47.428  INFO 29888 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-13 20:27:47.442 ERROR 29888 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4565) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5388) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1389) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:976) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:473) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:994) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:469) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:254) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:309) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:306) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.study.StudyApplication.main(StudyApplication.java:14) [main/:na]

2019-09-13 20:27:47.533  WARN 29888 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2019-09-13 20:27:47.561  INFO 29888 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-13 20:27:47.569 ERROR 29888 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the following properties to your properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```